# Altium : Rule on connector

Tags: pcb, altium, cad

I use auto routing with Altium and I search a way to force routing a connector on Bottom layer (as I do PCB prototype myself, it easier to solder connector on Bottom side).
To do this, I create a room and place it on this component.
Then I create a rule on this room.
But, it doesn't work.
Can someone help me to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want. Do you want to place the connector to the bottom on the bottom side and start routing from there. Is the connector a Through-Hole or SMD part? Or do you want to route on a single layer only in general?

Comment: It's a true hole connector.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all PCB layout programs assume that the board will be produced commercially, with plated-through holes, so the programs don't make any provision for single-layer designs.

However, you could place a solid fill on the component side copper, not connected to any net, around the connector (or perhaps over the whole board).  This would force the program to connect to the connector on the bottom side.

For a simple board, you may find it best to route it manually, then you have full control of where the connections are made.  Even with (perhaps especially with!) complex boards, I do a lot of manual routing.

Comment: Although I would also recommend manual routing, Altium is able to define Routing Layers on a Rule basis (and you can scope these rules to e.g. regions or nets or components).

Comment: It's not a complex board. I can do manual routing, but as it is just for some prototype that I do myself, I don't want to spend too much time.

Comment: As you say it must work : I have defined a ROOM on the component and define a query for this room : not isComponent. In PCB Rule, I create a Routing Layer for this room and I select only Bottom side. But it is not applied in autorouting
I also try to change the Track width for this room, but it is not applied in autorouting. Strangely, when I start the manual routing, it change the track width in this room (so, I suppose that the rule is correctly configured). Doing the same (track width) for a SMD component works in autorouting. I'm lost.

Comment: From the Altium website: To check that a rule is targeting the correct objects, copy the rule's Query into the filter panel and Apply it. Only those objects targeted by the rule should appear. - Have you tried that to see if your rule matches correctly?

Comment: It works when I use Manual routing. Can you try to route a component(true hole) only on SOLDER Layer?